# Controlling when Twitter Bootstrap decides to go into 'narrow' mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know the right term, but if you look at [this site](http://cosi236b.courses.salas.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/), you will see that as you make the browser window narrower, at some point the right nav bar jumps to the bottom to accommodate the width. I've been looking for the parameters or css that determines that width, because I would rather it narrow the main page some more before doing the jump.

Comment: Read the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses CSS media queries to control this.

Right now the site is using the `col-md-*` classes which use a 992 pixel breakpoint (the point at which the layout changes). If you want it to get narrower before stacking, you'd change the `col-md-9` and `col-md-3` to `col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3`, so that the collapse/stacking doesn't occur 768 pixels.

http://bootply.com/113030

If you don't want the colums to ever stack (and the sidebar not to drop below the content) you'd use the `col-xs-*` classes.